# JavaSscript Regex Only All Capitals

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression that gets a word only if every letter is capitalized (this also includes underscores).

Heres the code im using now. `/\b[A-Z_]+/g`

"This IS a NEW_SENTENCE to HELP_EXplain my PROblem."

In the above sentence all the letters that are capitalized will be selected. Even if they are apart of a word that has lowercase letters. How can i fix my code so only words with all capital letters and / or underscores are selected? (In this case from the sentence above, 'IS' and 'NEW_SENTENCE' should be the only words selected.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a word boundary (`\b`):

```
/\b[A-Z_]+\b/
```

This will match words with only capital letters and `_`.

It matches `IS`, `NEW_SENTENCE`, and **NOT** `HELP_EXplain`, `PROblem`.

The `\b` matches *positions* that are preceeded by a non-word character and followed by a word character (and the inverse).

Answer (score 0):

Add word boundaries from both sides, start and end.

```
/\b[A-Z_]+\b/
```